# Tab bar still highlighted

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios5

I have an app with a tabbar when you tap a item you will be send to another viewController. But when i come back the selected item is still highlighted.

Does anyone know how to unselect this?

For a Tablecell u can do;

```
     [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:[tableView indexPathForSelectedRow] animated:NO];
```

but how about an TabBar Item?

Comment: where did you add [tabs setSelectedItem:nil]; in your code? 

I tried adding it to the "viewWillAppear" method so when you come back it un-highlights it. However, this didn't work.

Any help would be great :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the UITabBar has no UITabBarController, you can use `[tabs setSelectedItem:nil];`.
If there is a controller, `[controller setSelectedViewController:nil];` should deselect the tab.